# dotnet core - missing csproj.metaproj

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core, .net-core

When building a MVC project on Ubuntu the following error occurs:

```
/home/user1/.local/share/Trash/files/pangolin.2/Pangolin.Web/src/Pangolin.Web/Pangolin.Web.csproj.metaproj : error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Could not find file '/home/user1/.local/share/Trash/files/pangolin.2/Pangolin.Web/src/Pangolin.Web/Pangolin.Web.csproj.metaproj'.
0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)
```

When building the same project on Windows there are no compilation errors.

The dotnet version on both machines is 1.0.0-rc4-004771. The project is build using the `dotnet build` command in both environments.

Comment: Do you have a `global.json`?

Comment: no, there is no global.json tha't part of the solution, however VS2017 did backup a global.json file during migration dotnet 1.1 before removing it.

Comment: @Levon Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was with the directory structure. Make sure any external projects are added to the src directory. Alternatively, you could add the external project as a NuGet dependency.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a very similar problem: It was building successfully on my DevMachine (Windows10), but failing in CI (Ubuntu 14.04).

My Directory Structure:

```
.gitignore
package/
     deployment_package.zip

src/
    .vs/
    MyService/
        MyService.csproj

    MyService.Tests/
        MyService.Tests.csproj

    MyService.sln
```

It would fail when I would run `dotnet build` at the `.sln` folder level, but *succeed* when I built each .csproj.

My working Rake task:

```
task :dotnet_build do
  Dir["#{SRC_DIR}/**/*.csproj"].each do |csproj_path|
    raise "Error building: #{csproj_path}" unless system("dotnet build #{csproj_path} --framework netcoreapp1.1")
  end
end
```

EDIT:
`dotnet build` has problems building with multiple cores.
setting the `/m:1` flag fixes this problem.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same with Travis. If you're, too, then would you mind sharing you `.travis.yml` file?

Comment: @nopara73, I am not using travis, and have migrated away from this solution. I found that there was a parallel error when compiling. I can now target the `.sln` file, and add the flag `/maxcpucount:1` to eliminate those parallelization errors.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem was with the directory structure. Make sure any external projects are added to the src directory. Alternatively, you could add the external project as a NuGet dependency.

Solves my problem.
I added every project to the **src** folder:
./src/project1
./src/project2

And i have a **global.json**:
./global.json

```
{ "projects": [ "src"],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.4"
  }
}
```